# Jar file: load configuration files in jar

Tags: java, jar, config

I exported a project that reads 2 configuration files. However, when I execute the jar, it gets this error:

```
    Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: config/dbConnection.config (No such file or directory)
    Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: config/test.config (No such file or directory)
    com.smart.ets.services.ServiceException: com.smart.ets.services.ConfigErrorException
        at com.smart.ets.services.TransactionServiceImpl.getConfigData(TransactionServiceImpl.java:30)
        at com.smart.ets.controllers.Simulator.getTransactionSimulationResults(Simulator.java:41)
        at com.smart.ets.controllers.Simulator.main(Simulator.java:26)
    Caused by: com.smart.ets.services.ConfigErrorException
        ... 3 more
    mickey91@mickey-espiritu:~/Documents/Dropbox$ java -jar ETS.jar
    Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: config/dbConnection.config (No such file or directory)
    Error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: config/test.config (No such file or directory)
    com.smart.ets.services.ServiceException: com.smart.ets.services.ConfigErrorException
        at com.smart.ets.services.TransactionServiceImpl.getConfigData(TransactionServiceImpl.java:30)
        at com.smart.ets.controllers.Simulator.getTransactionSimulationResults(Simulator.java:41)
        at com.smart.ets.controllers.Simulator.main(Simulator.java:26)
    Caused by: com.sm

art.ets.services.ConfigErrorException
    ... 3 more
```

Any way to fix this? It works if I run the project(not the jar file of the project)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You neglect to mention how you're accessing the files, but from the error it looks like you're trying to access them as files--but they're not, they're resources on the classpath.

As such, you should be using [getResourceAsStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29). The name of the resource would be the package-relative path.